# Why are delayed definitions in scoping functions not documented?

Tags: scoping, documentation, undocumented, language-design

As outlined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121173/121), `:=` may be used in scoping constructs like `With` to give delayed definitions, but this is undocumented.

This has been in the language since at least *Mathematica* 4.0.  It is very useful and it does not appear to be "dangerous" that I can see.  I cannot think of *any* good reason for this to have remained undocumented for so long.

Is there an argument to be made for hiding this important functionality?

Comment: Have you asked WRI Support? :)

Comment: @Kuba No.  I like exploring things here more.  Perhaps someone will give a reason I never even considered (this happens more often than I'd like!) and if not its visibility likely provides a greater impetus to WRI to document it than a simple suggestion from a random non-premium user.

Comment: @Kuba p.s. [(119915)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119915/121) *Have you asked WRI Support?* ;-)  I still haven't come up with a good answer to that question but I intend to give it more thought.

Comment: Doesn't this question fit perfectly the clause "The question is out of scope for this site. The answer to this question requires either advice from Wolfram support or the services of a professional consultant."? Perhaps, if Leonid drops in and he is considered to be a professional consultant....

Comment: @IstvánZachar You are welcome to vote to close.  If the community wishes to close this question I will not treat myself as special and reopen it.  I genuinely wonder if there is some reason, and in similar cases people *have* pointed out something I completely missed, or otherwise the question lead to important information.  I am glad these were not closed: [(58963)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58963/121),
[(59979)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59979/121),
[(89093)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89093/121)

Comment: I would have voted to close weren't I interested in the answer. But I used this method to give you a push toward what Kuba has suggested : )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This now seems to be documented officially, see the **Details** section on [With](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html), since version 13.2. There was no obvious update to core functionality that might explain why it was added at that version change. So I guess it was either an oversight with very low priority, or something internal that we will never learn.

```
With[{x:=x0, …}, expr] inserts the unevaluated form x0 into expr.
```

Good that it's there after (at least) 23 years, v4 in 1999.

Comment: better late than never :).  But still Mathematica documentation are the best of anything else I've seen.

Comment: @Nasser Agreed. And it explains the very gentle learning curve, compared to many other languages.