# Avoiding redundancy in Table expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Often I will have a table with different mutations to the same value and I end up repeating the same expression multiple times. A simple example:

```
Grid[Table[{i*100 + 17, PrimeQ[i*100 + 17]}, {i, 0, 20}]]
```

So, in this example the expression i*100+17 is repeated twice, once to show what the value is, then a second time to compute whether the value is prime.

How can write the expression more economically so that the linear expression is used only once and not repeated?

Comment: something like `Grid[Table[{j = i*100 + 17, PrimeQ[j]}, {i, 0, 20}]]`?

Comment: `With[]` and other scoping constructs are usable within `Table[]`, you know...

Comment: There are many possibilities, but perhaps you're looking for something like: `Table[{j,PrimeQ[j]},{j,Table[100i+17,{i,0,20}]}]` or the simpler version `Table[{j,PrimeQ[j]},{j,100 Range[0,20]+17}]`.

Comment: There is a duplicate I failed to find, even though I gave an answer there. But it is hard to find `{#, #}& [1 +1]`.

Answer (score 2):

I do not feel that the existing answers are quite "safe" as shown.

m_goldberg's code does not localize `i` correctly, e.g.

```
i = "fail!";

Grid[With[{j = i 100 + 17}, Table[{j, PrimeQ[j]}, {i, 0, 20}]]]
```

> ```
> 17+100 fail!  False
> 17+100 fail!  False
> 17+100 fail!  False
> . . .
> ```

This is subtle as normally `i` is localized by `Table` but here is it evaluated ouside `Table`.  This could be improved by using the [delayed form of `With`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/122061/121) but note that the expression will be evaluated as many times as `j` appears which could be significant in some code.

Nasser's code has a similar problem in that `j` is not localized which could interfere with other code.

### Solutions

Here are three methods that each scope properly. (`Grid` omitted for clarity.)

```
(* Function *)

Table[{#, PrimeQ[#]} &[i 100 + 17], {i, 0, 20}]


(* replacement - "injector pattern" *)

Table[i 100 + 17 /. j_ :> {j, PrimeQ[j]}, {i, 0, 20}]


(* Table dummy iterator *)

Table[{j, PrimeQ[j]}, {j, {i 100 + 17}}, {i, 0, 20}] // First
```

Comment: I'd actually have put `With[]` inside the `Table[]` and not outside, were I the one writing...

Comment: @J.M. I suspected that might have been the intent which is why I left a note for `m_goldberg`, expecting he would address the issue. :-)