# Condition usage clarification

Tags: functions, scoping, documentation

[ref / Condition / Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) says:

> `lhs := Module[{vars}, rhs /; test ]` allows local variables to be shared between `test` and `rhs`.

Well, thank you very much, of course they are shared, both `test` and `rhs` are inside the same `Module`!

Jokes aside, **the question is**: what author wanted to tell the user? How to rephrase that to make it clear and compact?

IMO when one knows then it is kind of understandable, but for learning purposes it is just confusing/meaningless as it was for me for a very long time.

Comment: p.s. I'm not planning to self answer :)

Comment: Related: "[Question on Condition (/;)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5866016/590388)."

Comment: In this case, the statement is kind of obvious, but the consequences are not. This form allows one to carry out some computations inside `Module`, that would involve local variables. Then, at some point, we may decide whether or not the rule (definition) matches as a whole, based on those computed values, by wrapping the rest of the code in `Module` inside `Condition`. If the condition does not hold, the pattern matcher pretends that the whole computation didn't take place, and goes on trying other rules / definitions. This semantics can't be easily reproduced had this form been absent.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin The problem is that these really important consequences aren't mentioned in the cited sentence in any way: we could speak only about contextual *hint*, and a hint isn't a kind of good documentation. It is good however that at the end of this sentence we currently have a link to an example which reveals the main point (this link wasn't present before version 6).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Agreed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never understood what that line in the documentation meant until I saw use of it in answers on Stack Overflow, i.e. [Partial evaluation in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1492876).  As such I am in the camp that feels this documentation could be written more explicitly for a user who is not already familiar with its use.

I propose something along these lines:

> For `With`, `Block`, and `Module` there exists a special construct `lhs := With[{vars}, body /; test]`.  In this specific instance the `Condition` applies to the entire definition upon `lhs` as if it were `lhs := rhs /; test` but in which `test` may depend on the localization and evaluation of `vars`.  This construct applies also to `RuleDelayed`, `UpSetDelayed`, and `TagSetDelayed` (short forms `:>`, `^:=` and `/: :=`).
>
> The scoping construct must constitute the entire right hand side of the assignment or rule, and the `Condition` must constitute the entire body of the scoping construct, less any additional `Condition` applied to each.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the meaning of this sentence is stupidly verbatim: the author simply notes the (almost obvious) fact that this construct allows sharing the localized by `Module` variables between the `Condition` and the `rhs` (which resides inside of the `Module`). In contrast, if we move the `Condition` outside of the `Module`, we won't have the localized variables shared between the `rhs` and the `Condition`:

```
f[x_] := Module[{u}, u] /; EvenQ[u]

f[2]
```

> ```
> f[2]
> ```

Probably this shouldn't be in the **Details** section: this statement is too obvious to reside there, it doesn't add something meaningful. But from the other side, there are some non-obvious under-documented "smart" rules on how different scoping constricts interact with each other: may be the author simply stresses that this obvious behavior is *by design* and we may trust it without risk...

Comment: Of course it is obvious that the variables can be shared on both sides of the `Condition` when it's within a scoped block, but what isn't obvious is that it affects the execution of `f`, i.e. if the condition fails the evaluator tries another version of `f`, if there is one.

Comment: @rcollyer Yes, but this doesn't follow from the cited statement...

Comment: I don't think that's true, in context with the forms described above it. Could it be a little more clear, possibly. But, I have never found it unclear.

Comment: @rcollyer Again, what you call "not obvious" comes from the other statements and examples on that page, not from the cited sentence. I mean that without the cited statement we would have the same information, so it is superfluous. It never confused myself but obviously confuses the OP...

Comment: I think I see where we differ. To me, the details section is the spec and should contain things like that, and the examples should help elucidate it. I don't think the examples alone should introduce the various syntaxes. (Obviously, that holds more weight when there are more than 4 examples, but it is the principle that matters. And, there are undoubtedly examples that don't follow that, but, again, principles.) Could the wording be improved, sure. But, superfluous? No.

Comment: @rcollyer I agree that the *not obvious* point is very important and should better be in the **Details** section than in the examples (as it is currently). [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123217/condition-usage-clarification/123248#comment333276_123217) comment of mine expands my point.

Comment: Thinking about it, I think my objection is to the word "superfluous" as I don't think it is. But, it is mostly semantics. :)

Answer (score 1):

some alternatives:

> - "**Condition** can be used inside **Module**"
> - "variables used in *rhs* and *test* can be localized"
> - "variables used in *rhs* and *test* can be localised using **Module**"
> - "variables can be used in both *rhs* and *test* and at the same time be localised with the use of **Module**"
> - "local variables can be used with the **Condition** construct"

My understanding is that the

> "shared between *test* and *rhs*"

part is superfluous.

As `Module` isn't necessary for the sharing of variables between *rhs* and *test*:

```
f[x_] := (u^2 /; (u = x - 1) > 0)
```

nor is it necessary for [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html#123) computation;

```
g[x_] := (x - 1)^2 /; (x - 1) > 0

g[0] => g[0]

g[6] => g[25]
```

I suspect this was written to tell new users that it is possible to combine **Module** with **Condition**.